# css height issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am having issue with the height of the sidebar .. i use **jQuery** to measure the height of the content and then add this height to sidebar to show the *sidebar shadow*. but its is giving issues in IE.

this link of the website is : http://www.norwichkitty.com/business-directory/

please check the left sidebar shadow issue ..

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var blockheight = $('.right-content').height();
    $('.sidebar').css('height', blockheight);
});
```

and its **CSS** view is

```
element.style {
    height: 1592px;
}
.sidebar {
    background: url("../img/sidebar-shadow.png") repeat-y scroll right center transparent;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 305px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

if is there any CSS solution to get rid of this issue .. please let me know ..

thank you all

Comment: Why are you using position:relative and z-index here?

Comment: i am just trying to fix the height issue ..

Comment: Are you clearing your floats?

Comment: please check the link .. http://www.norwichkitty.com/business-directory/

Comment: would this help ?? http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/ .. Not on windows.. so,cant check ur site.. but,overflow-y isnt supported by IE properly.. the link shd help u if the bug us caused by `overflow-y`

Answer (score 0):

You can widen the image to the width of the sidebar then make it the background image of the whole table Then no matter what the height of the content, the side-bar image with repeat on the y axis.

```
background: url(LINK_TO_IMAGE.png) repeat-y;
```

(ps. Is there any reason is has to be a table?)